# Understanding Ruby blocks. Why does Rspec do this?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand when to use Ruby blocks, and I see that in order to configure `rspec-rails`, you need to do something like this:

```
RSpec::configure do |config|
  config.foo = bar
end
```

Why in this case would be useful to do this as a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s only sugar. This is the (simplified) source:

```
module Rspec
  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= RSpec::Core::Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield configuration if block_given?
  end

  # rest omitted
end
```

See the source at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core.rb

This means you could also write

```
config = Rspec.configuration
config.foo = bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it gets tedious to prefix everything with `RSpec.configuration`.  Which do you like better?

```
RSpec.configuration.some_config_option = 5
RSpec.configuration.some_other_config_option = 6
RSpec.configuration.yet_another_config_option = :foo
```

Or:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.some_config_option = 5
  c.some_other_config_option = 6
  c.yet_another_config_option = :foo
end
```

Obviously, you could write `c = RSpec.configuration` and then use the `c.` syntax after that...but the block also nicely scopes/delimits the configuration code.

Answer (score 1):

Within a block, you change scope.  I believe you are scoped to RSpec here, within the block.  I also believe it's a convenience to be able to just say config.foo = bar within the block ( imaging you have 20+ configurations ).